# What's causing warnings when clicking a link in a newsletter/email message?

Tags: email, links, newsletter

I've created a html email newsletter (sending it through campaign monitor) and some of my receivers complain that they get a warning when they're clicking on links in my email.

> Warning this web page is not secure...

Is this something that's built into Outlook or IE? The strange thing is that this warning doesn't appear on all email links... just some of them. If it was on all links that would be OK.

Comment: Are any of the links to https pages?

Comment: Is that the *exact* message? I'm not getting anything in a search for it. Also, adding on to Paul's question, are they getting that message when they *click* or when they *arrive* at the URL? That would give some indication what application is actually issuing the error. It's a bit odd that you're asking about both Outlook and IE, given one isn't even a mail client.

Comment: @paulmorriss: Yes it's a https page. Maybe it's better to link to the http version? which then redirects to the https?

Comment: @Su': I asked about IE and Outlook since I don't know if the error pops up because of Outlook or because of IE (since it is the default web browser).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Explorer has a 'feature' to warn the user if they are visiting a page that contains 'mixed content' (secure and unsecured items). If the user's connection to their email is secure (For example, using Outlook Web Access) and they click on a link that goes to a non-https page, they will get a warning. This can also happen if you have an https page that has non-https links to images and/or script/css.

Find out if the emails are being viewed over a secure connection and, if so, try to use links that go to https urls.

Comment: It's linked via Campaign Monitors tracking links. This seems to be the problem. Thanks.